# Cocoa combo box like Safari

Tags: cocoa

Using Cocoa, I'd like to create a "combo box" as seen in Safari - think "select your state" where you click it, it drops down and has every option listed, and you choose them.  This differs from the standard NSComboBox because it doesn't have a blank line in it.  And it's also not so totally ugly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like an [`NSPopUpButton`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPopUpButton_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?